# The type org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanNameGenerator cannot be resolved Without Maven

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

First of all, I'm not using Maven as Maven plugin is not getting installed into my Eclipse. It throws 502 Exception code. Then I tried to create a dynamic web project and added spring jars (Context, Core, Webmvc) under lib and configured to build path.

Then I have created a Config class, but it throws

```
The type org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanNameGenerator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I googled it, but everyone is referring to have spring context jar. What else could be missing?

My simple code

```
package com.sbf.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sbf.spring")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the `spring-beans` jar. Try adding this also in your dependencies

Comment: Perfect pleft. Helped me